# Let $z$ be any point in $A\cap B\cap C$ and let $w$ be any point satisfying $|w-2-i|<3$.Then find $|z|-|w|+3.$

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $A,B,C$ be three sets of complex numbers as defined below:
$A=\{z:\text{Im} z\geq 1\}$,
$B=\{z:|z-2-i|=3\}$
$C=\{z:\text{Re}((1-i)z)=\sqrt2\}$
Let $z$ be any point in $A\cap B\cap C$ and let $w$ be any point satisfying $|w-2-i|<3$.Then find $|z|-|w|+3.$

---

Let $z=x+iy$.Then set $A$ is the set of points on and above the line $y=1$.
Set $B$ is the set of points on the circle $(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2=9$ and $C=\text{Re}((1-i)(x+iy))=\sqrt2$
$x+y=\sqrt2$
Hence $A\cap B\cap C$ has only one point of intersection.
 
I do not know how to solve it further.I am stuck here.

Comment: If any of the answeres below were useful to you, then you should [upvote](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) all answers you find useful and [accept](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that was most useful to you. It is a way to show that you have found the answer to your question and it shows your appreciation. Now it seems like you still need help. If answers are not useful to you, then it helps if you say why not. This helps others to help you. For more information [read this](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you wrote, we have 
$$y\ge 1$$
$$(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2=9$$
$$x+y=\sqrt 2$$
Solving the system gives that
$$z=x+yi=\frac{1+\sqrt 2-\sqrt{7+6\sqrt 2}}{2}+\frac{-1+\sqrt 2+\sqrt{7+6\sqrt 2}}{2}i$$

By the way, the intersection points between the cirlce and the line passing through $(0,0)$ and $(2,1)$ are
$$\left(\frac{10\pm 6\sqrt 5}{5},\frac{5\pm 3\sqrt 5}{5}\right).$$
Hence, noting that $(0,0)$ is inside the circle, 
$$0=\sqrt{0^2+0^2}\le |w|\lt \sqrt{\left(\frac{10+ 6\sqrt 5}{5}\right)^2+\left(\frac{5+ 3\sqrt 5}{5}\right)^2}=3+\sqrt 5.$$
Thus, the answer is
$$|z|-\sqrt 5\lt |z|+3-|w|\le |z|+3,$$
i.e.
$$\sqrt{5+3\sqrt 2-\sqrt{7+6\sqrt 2}}-\sqrt 5\lt |z|+3-|w|\le \sqrt{5+3\sqrt 2-\sqrt{7+6\sqrt 2}}+3.$$